# How can i get client request from socket.io connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, server

My server renders any page with object for example: 
d = {userId: 20, post: 190, title: 'Post'}
So, how can i get this object there:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    clientReq = // how get it?
    console.log(clientReq.userId);
});
```

Comment: combine express with socket.io

Comment: @niba i wanted do it without express